# Screen flickering and tearing with both intel and nvidia gpu on 16.10

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 16.10, nvidia-prime, flicker, tearing

These issues with multi-gpu machines on Linux are becoming extremely boring. I had 16.04 on my computer and I managed it to make it work fine with the intel card. Then I installed 16.10, huge flickering and tearing with both cards (intel+nvidia 950m). Then I installed back 16.04 no flickering but after the updates and upgrades, tearing persists with both cards. On each intallation, I tried all the latest drivers such as 364, 367, 370. I have no idea about what to do anymore.

Thanks in advance,